# How to get content assist for "for loop" anywhere in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, after a line like this:

List list = new ArrayList();

Typing "for" just beneath, and followed by "ctrl-space" (by default), will bring several options that can help completing this "for loop":
[image: assist]

But if the variable "list" is declared far from here (e.g. as a class field) which may not be directly inferred from this context, or there are many Lists declared,then the assistance doesn't work well:

[image: not work]
   @@ split line ---

[image]

In some cases, Eclipse can assist, but just don't work for member variable. E.g. manually type "another" and ENTER after the ":" didn't persuade Eclipse to guess about it....

(P.S. workable case:

Auto guessed

[image: auto guessed]

Entered wanted name, and ENTER, works great

[image: entered wanted name, and ENTER, works great])

Does anyone have any tip to make this assistance work under such scenarios?

Comment: It works well: since nothing can be inferred from the context, it generates a foreach block skeleton and lets you fill the parts it can't guess.

Comment: Please see the #2 and #3 picture. In some cases, Eclipse can assist, but just don't work for member variable. E.g. manually type "another" and ENTER after the ":" didn't persuade Eclipse to guess about it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I usually do to solve the content assist with for loop is the following:

- create a local variable by typing collection variable that is declared far above and a semicolon:

  ```
  list;
  ```
- press Ctrl+2 L
- Eclipse generates a new local variable declaration which looks like this:

  ```
  List list2 = list;
  ```
- type my foreach and autocomplete with Ctrl+space getting the following:

  ```
  List list2 = list;
  for (Object object : list2) {
  }
  ```
- place cursor on list2 in the for loop declaration and press Alt+Shift+I which stands for inline variable.
- this results in what you want to achieve. The effort is minimal after some practicing:

  ```
  for (Object object : list) {
  }
  ```

Answer (score 13):

I followed Ashutosh Jindal's tip and I managed to configure the template that works (tested with Kepler release). Here it is:

```
for (${iterable_type:elemType(iterable)} ${iterable_element:newName(iterable_type)} :  ${iterable:var(java.lang.Iterable)}) {
    ${cursor}
}
```

The main point was to change **localVar** to **var** in the template definition (the [Eclipse docs](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-template-variables.htm) clearly explain this).

How to use it:

1. Print the template name (**foreach** for default template) and hit Enter. The template will be used with default collection selected by Eclipse (the latest collection declared)
2. Hit TAB twice to jump to collection element. You will get drop down list with all iterable collections that apply.
3. Use UP/DOWN arrows to select desired collection, hit Enter. Eclipse will adjust element type and name (very cool).

[Click for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2jrS.png)

This works almost as good as Intellij templates. The drawbacks are:

- template does not include arrays (as opposed to default **foreach** template). For arrays you have to define another template.

Comment: Awesome, this should have way more upvotes. I struggled to find solution for this and was just about to write my own, but luckily ended here and saved my time.

Comment: @summerian any idea how to extend this logic  to include arrays also?

Answer (score 6):

I have not tried this myself, but take a look at the code template definition. For example, the `foreach` code template is defined in Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates as follows :

[image: Definition of foreach]

The definition is as follows :

```
for (${iterable_type} ${iterable_element} : ${iterable}) {
    ${cursor}
}
```

Notice the variables being used such as `iterable_type`.

Now take a look at **[this](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-template-variables.htm)** Eclipse help page.

There is a variable there called `${id:localVar(type[,type]*)}` which is described as follows :

```
Evaluates to a local variable or parameter visible in the current scope that is a subtype of any of the given type. If no type is specified, any non-primitive local variable matches.
${array} is a shortcut for ${array:localVar(java.lang.Object[])}, but also matches arrays of primitive types.
${collection} is a shortcut for ${collection:localVar(java.util.Collection)}.
${iterable} is a shortcut for ${iterable:localVar(java.lang.Iterable)}, but also matches arrays.
```

A screenshot of the same :

[image: Variable]

I believe that if you wanted to increase the scope from which the `foreach` template infers it's variables, you may have to edit the template definition with the appropriate variable.

Let me know if this helps. Unfortunately, I have not delved into editing the code templates before so shall not be able to give a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks. Did more research about it but didn't get 100% perfect solution. A workaround http://stackoverflow.com/a/2358355/367860 helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Years later, if you enter the name of the field/variable you can press Quick Fix (⌘+1) and in the quick fix menu you can choose different types of for-loops for the collection or array.
[image: Automatically generate for-loop using Quick Fix]